# Creating an url list by iterating date through a few years

Tags: python, date, for-loop, web-scraping, web-crawler

> http://weather.ap.polyu.edu.hk/displayHandler.php?**year=2018&month=8&date=19**&optStation=6100&optElement=f1&isFlag=

Hi everyone! I am an architecture student who is trying to scrap some data up from a weather station website. I don’t know much about `web-crawling` so I am trying to use a chrome extensive called `data miner` to download all the images of the following link down.

To do that, I first need to create a CSV file containing all the links and I am wondering if there is a faster way for me to do it using `dates` in Python.

As we can see from the image, the only changing parameter for all these links would be the date period. For the date, I need it to iterate for 3 whole years.

I have tried slicing in Python but there are too many statements confusing myself. So I am wondering if importing `date` can help with that. Does anyone mind showing me how I could iterate thru these years and fit the day month year exactly into the URL, and eventually end up with a CSV file?

I prefer using Python.

Thanks so much!

Comment: There is a python package called `urlparse` which can help you split up a URL into multiple separate pieces. And then yes using the `datetime` python package can probably help you iterate through every day. Then you can save that to a CSV file pretty easily. Stackoverflow isn't really meant for broad design questions, so I would suggest trying your best at getting something working, and then make a question here if you get stuck on something specific or an error happens that you can't fix.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the exact start and end dates?

Comment: The classes `datetime` and `timedelta` will be immensely helpful here.  You should make an attempt and show us what you've tried so we can help you debug.  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, urlunparse


def all_dates(start_date, end_date):
    current_date = start_date
    one_day = timedelta(days=1)
    while current_date != end_date:
        yield current_date
        current_date += one_day
    yield current_date


def generate_url(date):
    base_url = 'http://weather.ap.polyu.edu.hk/displayHandler.php'
    parsed = urlparse(base_url)
    query = urlencode({
        'year': date.year,
        'month': date.month,
        'date': date.day,
        'optStation': 6100,
        'optElement': 'f1',
        'isFlag': ''
    })
    return urlunparse((
        parsed.scheme,
        parsed.netloc,
        parsed.path,
        parsed.params,
        query,
        parsed.fragment
    ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_date = datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=1)
    end_date = datetime(year=2018, month=1, day=1)

    with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
        for date in all_dates(start_date, end_date):
            f.write('{}\n'.format(generate_url(date)))
```

You didn't respond about what the exact start/end dates were supposed to be so I just had to guess for an example (Jan 1, 2015 - Jan 1, 2018). You can simply change those two variables, `start_date` & `end_date`, to
whatever you want.

[`outfile.csv`](https://bpaste.net/show/71487ecc0fe2)

---

You could also use Python to download those images instead of using a chrome extension but I tried to keep this answer simple for now.